# Smithing doesnt go over 100

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have reached 100 Smithing.

But when I wear:

Ring - "Weapons and armor can be improved 23% better" (self enchanted)

Necklace - "Weapons and armor can be improved 23% better" (self enchanted)

Gloves - "Weapons and armor can be improved 17% better"

My skill still says Smithing = 100. Does this mean the above have no effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it does not.

The "Weapons and armor can be improved by X%" is only improving what you would *already* be able to make at Smithing level 100.

<strike>If you're trying to get your smithing to go *over* 100, you need "Fortify Smithing by X points."</strike>

According to the UESP, there are two items that will guarantee you find an item with the Fortify Smithing enchantment. Here's [one.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Silver-Blood_Family_Ring#Silver-Blood_Family_Ring) And here's [two.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Forgemaster%27s_Fingers)

It's worth noting that the second one is a random radiant quest, so you may not get it on your first attempt.

**EDIT**
I was mistaken, there is no "Fortify Smithing by X Points." The Fortify Smithing enchant only does the "Weapons and armor can be improved X% better."

However, even though your smithing skill *won't* go over 100, you will *still* get the benefits from the enchantment. For example, if you were to make a Legendary Dagger at 100 smithing, it might come out with, say, 14 damage. If you were to use your equipment to fortify your smithing and make the same dagger, you might get something to the effect of 20 damage, depending on what % of an increase there is from your gear/potions.

Comment: in other works, the above items do increase armor rating and weapon damage more then i could at smithing 100?

Comment: where can i find an item to disenchant to learn that skill?

Comment: @VaibhavGarg Yes, the items you already have will still improve the armor/damage more than you could've without them, even at level 100.